# Stacking Tiles (Hard algorithm)

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, graph, permutation

This is a question from a code competition, I am finding it unbelievably difficult to come up with any working algorithm to solve it. So I'm not really looking for the code but rather a step by step algorithm on how to solve it.

> #### Stacking Tiles
>
> Stacking tiles against the wall is one of Bongani's favourite pasttimes. His tiles all have the same thickness, but vary
>   in width and height. Bongani is given N tiles and has to use them in
>   the sequence given according to a set of rules. He can place a tile on
>   top of another only if it is narrower than the previously stacked
>   tile. Bongani is allowed to rotate the tiles by 90 degrees so that
>   width becomes height and height becomes width. He is also allowed to
>   discard a tile altogether. Given a list of tiles, help Bongani find
>   the highest stack he can build The example specifies tiles (3, 3),
>   (12, 5), (5, 8), (6, 10). To get the highest stack Bongani ignores the
>   first tile (3, 3) as it is smaller than the next tile. He uses the
>   next tile (12, 5) with 12 as the width and 5 as the height. He uses
>   the next two tiles with 8 as the width and 5 as the height followed by
>   6 as the width and 10 as the height.

The only thing I can possibly think of is getting every possible valid permutation of tiles and find the highest permutation. 
The exact question can be found here [http://www.olympiad.org.za/olympiad/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/2011PO-*R2*-Questions-0421.pdf](http://www.olympiad.org.za/olympiad/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/2011PO-_R2_-Questions-0421.pdf) (Question 5)

Comment: Did you understand my answer, or should I clarify anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an outline of dynamic programming solution:

You "move from left to right" and for each tile you figure out

- how high tower can I build by *using this tile unrotated*
- how high tower can I build by *using this tile rotated*
- how high tower can I build by *not using* this tile

The first key observation is that each question can be answered recursively ("how high tower can I build for the remaining tiles if the current width is updated according to my current choice?"). Pseudo code:

```
maxHeight(tiles, currentWidth) {

    // Base case
    if (tiles.isEmpty())
        return 0;  // no tiles -> maxHeight == 0

    int h = 0;
    currentTile = tiles[0]
    remainingTiles = tiles[1...]

    // Compute maxHeight for the case when not using current tile
    h = max(h, maxHeight(remainingTiles, currentWidth)

    // Compute maxHeight when using current tile
    if (currentWidth > currentTile.width)
        subHeight = maxHeight(remainingTiles, currentTile.width)
        h = max(h, subHeight + currentTile.height)

    // Compute maxHeight when using current tile rotated
    if (currentWidth > currentTile.height)
        subHeight = maxHeight(remainingTiles, currentTile.height)
        h = max(h, subHeight + currentTile.width)

    return h
}
```

The second key observation is that many of the invocations of `maxHeight` have the same arguments, which means that previous computations can be reused. You can either use memoization or tabulation (both are variants of dynamic programming) If you choose to use a tabulation matrix, it would look like this:

```
M[tileN][width] = the height of the tower possible to build from
                  tileN onwards with width 'width'
```

(As you may note `width` does not have a clear upper bound. This can be solved by mapping all values to `1, 2, 3, ...` before starting. Maximum width will then be 2N.)

Comment: Why are you sorting the tiles? I think you imagined a different and harder problem where you get to reorder the tiles.

Comment: oh, I thought I could use them in any order... Let me revise.

Comment: You're right that it is indeed simpler than I first thought.

Comment: Im struggling to understand with the recursion, why h ever changes 'int h = 0;' that runs everytime the method is called, so h is constantly resting

Comment: `h` is a local variable. There are as many `h` variables as there are calls to `maxHeight` on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quadratic time algorithm using dynamic programming. Let f(i) be the greatest height of a tower you can build using the ith block in the original orientation and no later blocks. Let g(i) be the greatest height of a tower you can build with the ith block rotated and no later blocks. Note that blocks can be omitted, so to compute f(i), you have to take 1 more than the maximum over all previous f and g values compatible with that orientation, and similarly for g(i). At the end, the answer is the maximum over all f(i) and g(i).

The following code shows code for f. Youc an write g similarly, or modify this to take another parameter for whether block i is in the original orientation.

```
public int f(int i)
{
    if (i == 0)
        return 1;
    if (memoF[i] > 0)
        return memoF[i];
    int maxFound = 1; // using just this block is legal
    for (int j = 0; j<i; j++){
        if (widths[i] < widths[j])
            maxFound = Math.max(f(j)+1,maxFound);
        if (widths[i] < heights[j])
            maxFound = Math.max(g(j)+1,maxFound);
    }
    memoF[i] = maxFound;
    return memoF[i];
}
```

Comment: This is way above my pay grade :/. Could you potentially try explain this more simply. But thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: @TamirShklaz: The first step might be to read the problem statement more carefully. From your comments about trying every permutation, it sounds like you think you can reorder the tiles, but the problem statement says you can't. So there are no permutations to try. Do you know what memoization or dynamic programming are?

Comment: I know about Dynamic programming vaguely, and virtually nothing about memoization. Do you know of any guides or tutorials available on the matter ?

Comment: If you Google dynamic programming, you should find among the first hits the following: the Wikipedia page on dynamic programming and a tutorial on CodeChef on dynamic programming. Please put in some time learning this important and basic technique which you are expected to know for competitive programming, and without which you won't understand the answers given here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is typical example for easy and effective solving using Backtracking.

You just go in sequence and try first things you can do, when you cant continue, you go back and try the one you did not try before. Just google "Sudoku Backtracking" there are a lot of pages explaing that.

The huge advantage of backtracking in this case is, it "cuts" off a lot scenariou which would make no sense, therefore it would be much more effective than trying to check every possible combination.
(like in sudoku, with backtracking, the most sudokus are solved in 1000-10000 steps, which is pretty good, given that the all possible combinations of numbers you can write are ~10^60)

Comment: You're suggesting an exponential time algorithm?